# How to ignore case when dealing with a variable in an if statement - Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, variables, prompt, case-sensitive

Am a complete beginner in Javascript and trying to use as simple as code as possible. Having some issues regarding case sensitivity when it comes to using a variable from a prompt inside an if statement. Here is the code in question. It works perfectly assuming the input is exactly 'French'

```
if (number => 1 && number <= 30) {
    var lang= prompt ("Which language do you want to translate into, French or German?");
}
while(lang != "French" && lang != "french" && lang != "FRENCH" && lang != "German" && lang != "german" && lang != "GERMAN" ) {
    alert("Only French or German is allowed");
    var lang= prompt ("Which language do you want to translate into, French or German?");
}   


    if (number == 1 && lang == "French") {
        alert("The translation is " +frenchNumbers[1]);
    }
    if (number == 2 && lang == "French") {
        alert("The translation is " +frenchNumbers[2]);
    }
    if (number == 3 && lang == "French") {
        alert("The translation is " +frenchNumbers[3]);
    }
```

I want the 'if' statements to also work if the user was to enter 'french' or 'FRENCH'. I have tried to use the next piece of code, but it cycles through the alerts from the beginning, which is not what I want. For example if I was to enter '3' and 'FRENCH' I would get the alerts for '1' and '2' first.

```
if (number == 1 && lang == "French" || lang == "french" || lang == "FRENCH") {
        alert("The translation is " +frenchNumbers[1]);
    }
    if (number == 2 && lang == "French" || lang == "french" || lang == "FRENCH") {
        alert("The translation is " +frenchNumbers[2]);
    }
    if (number == 3 && lang == "French" || lang == "french" || lang == "FRENCH") {
        alert("The translation is " +frenchNumbers[3]);
    }
```

I'm sure there's an easy work around, going a little crazy trying to work it out as all the information I've looked at is well above my skill level

Any help would be great

Thanks, Brad

Comment: You can use the string method .toLowerCase() (or toUpperCase) on your input, and compare it against an upper or lower case test value. For example, `lang.toLowerCase() === "french"`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase

Comment: ^ As you look through the documentation, you will see navigation on the left side of the page showing you other methods implemented by the "string prototype". In Javascript, that means that all strings have those methods available, like the example `lang.toLowerCase()`. Definitely worth taking a look at the other stuff available in that category, and on the Array prototype. Loads of useful stuff -- MDN should be your go-to resource for learning the javascript API.

Comment: Even better if you transform the value to lower case first so you're not calling the function a million times.  Like so: `let lang = prompt("French or German?").toLowerCase();`

Comment: ^ careful with that... if they hit cancel it will be an exception :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by Chris Baker, you can use `.toLowerCase()`. The code you need to adjust is as follows.

```
while(lang.toLowerCase() != "french" && lang.toLowerCase() != "german") {
...
if (number == 1 && lang.toLowerCase() == "french") {
...
```

Comment: The while loop isn't necessary, btw, IF would do the trick, also `if(["french", "german"].includes(lang.toLowerCase()))` if you wanna be fancy :p

Comment: @ChrisBaker - Oooo... nice one. A little less understandable for newer coders, but a very nice use of the language features! :)

Comment: Thanks so so much! Super fast reply and this has solved my problem perfectly! If the user wishes to enter 'FRenCh' (for whatever stupid reason) then they now can :)

I've saved your comment @ChrisBaker, I don't understand it, but I'm going to have a play around and see what it can do. Thanks again guys much appreciated! :)

Comment: @Brad - Chris's comment can be explained as follows. The ["french", "german"] is an array, and can be any hardcoded array such as this or a variable that holds an array. The `.includes(param)` is an array function that tests to see if the array has a value that matches `param`, and the `lang.toLowerCase()` you now understand. :)